# Install4j merge Projects

Tags: merge, install4j

i have two seperate Projects and want to merge them to one Project. 
i've created a new Project and on "Merge Project" i added both Project Files. 
After that on Screens & Actions i added the links to the Screens and Actions 
that i need from the Projects.

Now i need to configure install4j to make both merged Projects selectable as
 Components.

My question: how can i configure install4j that way? I cant see the Files on Files -> Installation Components

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i need to configure install4j to make both merged Projects selectable as
>   Components.

That is not how merged projects work. You can include certain elements from merged projects into the main project, but the merged project does not retain a separate identity.

Installation components can only be defined in the main project.

Comment: thanks alot i do unterstand install4j more and more.  i have another question but i will open a new post